# What can WebServices do that EJB can't?

Tags: web-services, ejb

Interoperability comes to mind (MS/Java).

Also, with EJB you need to distribute EJB interface, with WS you got WSLD (I know there's EJB extension for WSDL, but I'm not sure it's used).

Anything else?

Answer (score 1):

EJB is mostly about a programming model for how you implement callable Business Logic. You code is running in a container which looks after management, clustering, transactions and security. Your component can be called by and number of different mechansims including local Java Calls, RMI/IIOP for remote invocation and also Web Services, so yes your EJB can indeed have a WSDL and be callable fro other non-Java envrionments.

If you start instead from the point of view of having a WSDL, which probably will specify SOAP/HTTP, then you are free to implement that in many different technologies, and of cource invoke it via that specified protocol, which very many different clients can use. The big question is how easily you can deal with those quality of implementation issues - your chosen implementation environment may give a lot of help or leave a lot to you.

Summary: you're not really comparing like-with-like. Web Services is very about the interface, EJB very much about the implementation.

Comment: I see both "platforms" as interfaces and implementations.

Comment: I hit enter to soon :/


But I agree, EJB includes more implementation details and hence is more complete framework.

On the other hand both, EJB and WS specify the protocol for remote transactions, for example.

Comment: Web Services says nothing at all about implementation. It does indeed define protocols for security, transactions, sessions etc. It says nothing about how you implment it, gives no assistance in doing so. You usually go to some chosen framework to help you. Serious vendors supporting Web Services (the JEE camp and MS and many open source etc) all offer implementation help, EJB being one example.

Comment: True. MS, for example, uses MSDTC to implement WS-AT. App servers use JTA. Well, once you go cross-system, it's hard to dictate implementation, because you deal with so different systems.

One other thing... we keep thinking of WS as standard. But in reality, who implements WS-AT, other than MS and Java players?

Can you see WS-AT for PHP in the near future? Probably not. Does that mean that WS are really only serving MS to enter enterprise market, by solving already solved problems?

Comment: Actually I'm an IBM Java consultant, we make extensive use of Web Services in our products, and participate in communities with MS and many others to ensure inter-operability. We do do WS-AT etc. If you have interop needs then WebServices are a strong candidate. I'd argue that once you get to things such as WS-AT you're outside the PHP comfort zone.

Comment: But what would you choose for Java to Java system, eg. Websphere to Weblogic?

It's surprising, but JavaEE transactions are not always compatible across different vendors.

Comment: I would avoid distributed transactions if at all possible, even within a single vendor. For non-trivial integration scenarios you need decoupling, hence we tend to asynch messaging (and very careful design to achieve consistency) So I would tend to implement in JEE and expose Web Service interfaces for interop - we are usually in highy heterogenous environemnt.